# Cant find module 'prompt-sync'

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is very simple as I am just starting back to learn JavaScript. I understand the basics, the logic, but I've only ever done simple scripts embedded in HTML many years ago.
version I get the error:

Cannot find module prompt-script

I have installed the library using the following command with only 1 warning about missing
repository in the JSON.

```
npm install --save @types/prompt-sync
```

I also tried to delete the installed files and do it like:

```
C:\Users\Username\Project>npm install --save @types/prompt-sync
```

When it couldn't find the module the first time.

The script is very simple:

```
var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
//
// get input from the user.
//
var n = prompt('How many more times? ');
```

This of course is not what I wanna write but I must have the library installed wrong since I can't find the module. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something really simple.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are installing `@types/prompt-sync` (the TypeScript definitions for `prompt-sync` - even though you aren't using TypeScript) but requiring `prompt-sync`.

You have to install the package you are actually requiring, `prompt-sync`:

```sh
npm i prompt-sync
```